# Protractor Data Driven test with Cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumber, data-driven-tests

I am using Protractor with Cucumber and Typescript.
I want to know if data driven testing is possible at scenario level in cucumber using either if csv or json file.

Below is my code:
Feature file:

```
Feature: Test Search Functionality

  @smoke  @regression @search

  Scenario Outline: Search a parameter in application

    Given I login to Application
    Then I should be able to go to HomePage
    And I navigate to search modal-popup
    Then I should be able to search - "<SomeParameter>"
    When I click Logout button
    Then I should be able to log-out of Application
    |SomeParameter|
    |XXXXXXXX|
```

Note: Appropriate, step definition and page object are written to handle above scenario.

Here, rather than hard coding data in scenario, I want to pass it using some utility like csv or excel.

Comment: Yes, you can read values from a file.

Comment: Please let me know how, any git repo link would help me in implementing the same.

Comment: Please specify from what kind of file you want to get data.

Comment: I am looking for .csv implementation primarily; but json may also work

Comment: You can use `fs.readFileSync`. See the documentation: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options

Comment: Thanks, will try..